# Continuous function involved with integrals and limit

Tags: integration, limits, continuity

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function such that for all $A>0$ the integral $\int_{A}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$ converges. Suppose that $0<a<b$.

Show that

a. $\lim_{\in\rightarrow 0}\int_{\in a}^{\in b}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt=f(0)\ln (\frac{b}{a})$

b.$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\int_{T a}^{T b}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt=0$

I'm not sure how to compute the integral (which would help me out big time). Do I equate it to an arbitrary variable? But also in part a I'm not sure how the LHS relates to $\ln (\frac{b}{a})$.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For (a), set $u=\frac{t}{\epsilon}$ (change of variable) and argue you can swap limit and integral.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous, for $\epsilon>0$ small the integrand in the first integral is very close to $f(0)/t$, whose primitive is $f(0)\ln (t)$.

For the second part.  Define $I_{AB}=\int_A^Bf(t)/tdt$.  Then $I_{1B}$ has a limit as $B\to\infty$.  Therefore for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $B_0$ such that for all $B,C>B_0$, $|I_{1B} - I_{1C}|<\epsilon$.  This means that whenever $T>B_0/a$,
$$
\left|\int_{Ta}^{Tb}\frac{f(t)}tdt\right|<\epsilon
$$
which proves part (b).